# Dynamics CRM 2013: disable "Pending email warning" notification

Tags: email, outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When logging into CRM I get "Pending email warning" notification. The same happens when refreshing the page.

Screenshot:

[image]

I am using "Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 for Microsoft Office Outlook" but I can't find any messages that are not sent there.

How to fix this issue from CRM or from Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message is because you have some of the emails that are yet to be sent, maybe postponed. The only way to get rid of this warning is to cancel all the emails. Take a look at this article [Remove Pending Email Warning](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2012/03/14/crm-2011-pending-email-warning.aspx)

Another quick option is to use a `?skipNotification=1` parameter in the URL
eg. `http://xyz:5555/orgname/main.aspx?skipNotification=1`

Comment: I read the article, the solution was to use "Advanced find" on "Email messages". All the pending emails were there. I deleted them and the notification is gone.

Comment: This is not working in CRM 2016. Is any possibility to suppress this warning in URL?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the details from this [article] ...(http://www.hellokg.com/2015/02/13/pending-email-warning-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/)

- Go to Services \ Activities ...
- Select Email \ My Pending Emails ...
- ... and delete them